# Laravel computed field on the relation's of a model like a model attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have a model for `Flights`.
The `Flight` have a relationship with `payments_log`.

In the `payments_log` table there are two fields: `amount` and `type(Input/Output or add/sub)`.

I want to add a field on the `Flight` model for example `Total_amount`.

The `total_amount` on the `Flight` model will be a field that computed from `relationship`.

```
type   amount
I       5.0
I       10.0
O       2

Total_amount = I+I-O = 13
```

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) method on your `Flight` model that sums the `amount` column from the logs table:

```
public function getTotalAmountAttribute()
{
    // Sum log records of type I (add) 
    // and substract the sum of all log records of type ) (sub)
    return $this->paymentsLog()->where('type', 'I')->sum('amount') - $this->paymentsLog()->where('type', 'O')->sum('amount');
}
```

Then you can access it using:

```
$flight->total_amount;
```

Comment: Thank you, and what is the difference between $this->payableLogs() with $this->payableLogs?

Comment: `$this->paymentsLog` returns the collection of related `payments_log` records (as in it executes the query), where `$this->payableLogs()` returns the query builder instance.

Comment: Is there any way to see this field on the model collection when we select with find(id)?

Comment: Yes, add this property to your `Flight` class: `protected $appends = ['total_amount'];`. That will ensure it included on each flight record.